# How to test a mixin for a ModelViewSet

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Inside a project I am working on is a Django "app" with a few of mixins/base classes that work together with DRF's `ModelViewSet`s to handle everything related to soft deleting. The app is at the very bottom the dependency hiearchy and does not contain any routes. I would like not to have to use any models, viewsets, serializers or routes from any other app. Rather I would like to create a set of temporary models, viewsets, serializers, and routes that only exist while the test is running.

So far I have the following:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from django.db import models
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework import routers
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
from soft_delete.mixins import SoftDeleting
from soft_delete.models import SoftDelteable

class TestModel(SoftDelteable):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class TestSereializer:
    class Meta:
        model = TestModel
        fields = "__all__"


class TestViewSet(SoftDeleting, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = TestModel.objects.all()


class TestSoftDelete(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.router = routers.DefaultRouter()
        self.router.register(r"test", TestViewSet)
        self.d1 = TestModel.objects.create(name="D1", deleted_at=datetime.now())
        self.d2 = TestModel.objects.create(name="D2", deleted_at=datetime.now())
        self.a1 = TestModel.objects.create(name="A1")
        self.a2 = TestModel.objects.create(name="A2")

    def test_cant_list_deleted(self):
        response = self.client.get("/test/")
        self.assertEqual(len(response.data), 2)

    def test_can_retrieve_deleted(self):
        id = self.d1.id
        response = self.client.get(f"/test/{id}")
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

When I try to run this I get:

````
TestModel doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS
```

Which I can resolve by changing the model to be:

```py
class TestModel(ArchivableModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        app_label = "test"
```

I doubt this is enough, but in any event the route isn't actually registered, so I get a 404. This is where I'm stuck currently. I've no idea how to register the route. I've seen a question/answer here that uses `as_view` to process the requests without actually registering a route, but the issue with that is that it was mapping HTTP methods to ViewSet actions and I'm not sure how to get the retrieve action.
````